# SQL Server : multiple Select queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I am trying to show `sum(grand_total) where is_loyal = 1` and `sum(grand_total) where is_loyal = 0` together in the same result screen (`grand_total` column is in the same table for both). I have tried subqueries, join and case when but no luck so far. Is there a way to calculate and show the results together?

The only result I can find by subqueries is below, no matter how I change where clause gives me the same data. If I change my query a bit it throws error message

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 155
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrSPK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
  sum(case when loyal = 1 then grand_total end) [Total Loyalty],
  sum(case when loyal = 0 then grand_total end) [Total Spent non-loyalty]
from tablename
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when like this:

```
select
sum(case when loyal = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as grand_total_Loyal,
sum(case when loyal = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as grand_total_noneloyal
```

Comment: ::Facepalm:: Tried case in a different and unsuccessful way and now I see my mistake :)) Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: This query seems to be missing a `from` clause and a `group by` clause.

Comment: Hi GMB, i just gave him the the portion he asked for in the question. But yeah indeed the rest I didnt add it

Comment: Thank you guys, much appreciated. I handled the rest of the query, I used case clause totally wrong now I understand my mistake.

Comment: @Anil this answer does not return the sum of `grand_total` but it counts the number of rows. Why did you accept it?

Comment: @forpas sorry for my reply, because I changed it as below and then used it


`sum(case when is_loyalty = 1 then grand_total end) [Loyalty],
sum(case when is_loyalty = 0 then grand_total end) [Non-loyalty]`

Comment: @Anil so you used the code from my answer and accepted another answer?

Comment: @forpas sorry mate if I selected the wrong one as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method uses arithmetic:

```
select sum(loyal * grandtotal) as loyal_grandtotal,
       sum( (1 - loyal)  * grandtotal) as notloyal_grandtotal
from t
where loyal in (1, 0);
```

The more general solution is using a `case` expression.  However, if you have 0/1 flags they fit very easily into arithmetic calculations -- on reason why they are preferred over, say, string flags.